# How to recover wordpress blog from mysql db without wp - content

Tags: php, mysql, database, wordpress, phpmyadmin

Yes, as strange as it appears to be, due to an accident the entire site just blew away, including the wp-content, wp-include folders, etc. Only thing that remains with me is the mysql database through phpmyadmin. How can I retrieve posts, pages, etc from it?

I usually use the script installers for wordpress such as fantastico, etc. , not exactly familiar with detailed ftp procedure to install wordpress manually

Any help would be grateful.

Thanks in advance

Comment: well, do you have backups? It might be safer and best to restore from a backup if you have one. Maybe your provider has auto-backups? Check that first. If not, it gets real complicated as it is a case-by-case thing. [You could try this here](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/linux-and-open-source/how-to-recover-all-your-posts-from-a-wordpress-database/)

Comment: I'm afraid i am only left with a mysql database. And that's all. I've looked at the post earlier too, wasn't of much help

Comment: Well that post is getting data (specifically posts) from a wordpress mysql database, nothing else. So if all you have is a WP database, then it seems recoverable. If the WP data is gone, then the only option is to hope for a backup.

Comment: That seems little relieving @MrJack. How should I proceed onto it any way?

Answer (score 1):

As I said above, it is a case by case thing. Which version were you using? what were your plugins? were there any special directories? were there any special/custom bits of code? etc etc etc. If you didn't install yourself, that's all things someone would have to consider when recreating the installation and test for since auto-install scripts can install just about anything. It's a pain, but at least your content isn't completely lost.

So try following the database recovery linked in the comments, then install a new wordpress, then reinsert those recovered lines. After all, your question isn't really tailored for stack overflow, it might (and I'm not fully sure here) yeild more precise answers and be better suited for Server Fault.

Keep a full DB backup (untouched) somewhere, I have a feeling you may need to hire someone in the end if you cant get it back up yourself by just recreating a new WP and reinserting the data. It's just one of those things that sound simple to do, but it is very hard to explain because too much could go wrong. After all, you should have backed up your site automatically, every day. That way, it would already be restored.

Comment: yes you're right. I was finally able to retrieve the data in form of posts, users, comments and pages, sans the images. Would have to manually re-insert the images, thanks to having local directories before uploading. 

I faced a few different and strange difficulties, for which I'd be writing a separate blgo post and sharing. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try to make a new WP Website and install the plugins you used to have. And then replace the database tables by the ones you have saved.

Answer (score 0):

These guys seem to offer a plugin that may be able to help you import a database into a new site easily.

[WP Migrate DB Pro](https://deliciousbrains.com/wp-migrate-db-pro-1/?utm_expid=69603916-8.68eP7T92S6eHFCbo40BImg.1&utm_referrer=http%3A%2F%2Fwordpress.org%2Fsupport%2Ftopic%2Fplugin-wp-migrate-db-import-function%3Freplies%3D4)

It isn't a free plugin but if it saves you a lot of time and allows you to import your old database.

I'd do that first and then look at getting your old plugins reinstalled like the others mentioned.